# CoreData NSPredicate with more than one NSSet

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsset

At the moment I try to translate the following SQL Query to a NSPredicate:

```
SELECT name FROM person WHERE tournament='x' AND rankingID = (SELECT id FROM ranking WHERE place=1 AND round='final');
```

Ranking is a NSSet in Person.
I had try it like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "tournament = %@ AND ANY rankings.place = 1 AND ANY rankings.round = 'final'", selectedTournament!)
```

But that don't do what I want. :(

Comment: Rankings is a to many relationship? And the logic of anything in that relationship which matches is valid (it doesn't matter what it is)?

Comment: Person is a one to many Relationship to Rankings, and person is an one to one relationship to tournament

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I did it, here is my solution:

```
NSPredicate(format: "tournament = %@ AND SUBQUERY(rankings, $ranking, $ranking.place = 1 AND $ranking.round = 'final').@count > 0", selectedTournament!)
```